# Difference between HttpContext.Request.Path and HttpContext.Request.PathBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontext

I am wondering what's the difference between `HttpContext.Request.Path` and `HttpContext.Request.PathBase` in a Web API controller? I read the documentation but didn't understand what the intented difference should be, even after testing both properties:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostItem(ItemPostRequest itemPostRequest)
{   
    // Output: Path is: '/api/items'
    Debug.WriteLine($"Path is: '{HttpContext.Request.Path}'");
    
    // Output: PathBase is: ''
    Debug.WriteLine($"PathBase is: '{HttpContext.Request.PathBase}'");

    // [...]
}
```

When would `PathBase` be non-empty? I am on NET 5.0.

Comment: Probably when you configure `app.UsePathBase("/some-path")` (in the Startup.Configure method), but that's just a guess (that you could easily try)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You are right, see my answer below for more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As Camilo wrote, it's about [`app.UsePathBase("/some-path")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Adding `app.usePathBase("/mysite1")` one needs to call `/mysite1/api/items` instead of `/api/items` and then it looks like this:

```
Path is: '/api/items'
PathBase is: '/mysite1'
```

Obviously PathBase can be used to host multiple sites/APIs on one host.